# What do I need to configure to host django applications on linode?

Tags: django, deployment, hosting, linode

I am about to choose hosting provider for my Django project. I took a look on a [linode](http://www.linode.com/)
and it looks very promissing. It looks like very elastic solution but in my case this might be a disadvnatage since I'm not so experienced in servers configuration (alternative provider for me has great tools to quickly do the job, but linode has more competitive power/price ratio).

Do you have some experience in linode configuration for Django projects?

EDIT:
To be more precise: I am not so affraid about django packages installation but more about application server/database server/security/all that stuff configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you stick to the Django packages that your distribution provides (Ubuntu seems to be best) or use easy_install, Django is pretty easy to get going. The host that you're looking at, Linode, has [Django setup guides](http://library.linode.com/development/frameworks/python/django/) for a variety of distributions. I recommend [mod_wsgi with Ubuntu 10.04](http://library.linode.com/development/frameworks/python/django/apache-mod-wsgi-ubuntu-10.04-lucid) from that list.

I've personally used Django on my Linode, and it works fine. Well, in fact. For your intents and purposes you can think of a Linode as a dedicated server, and it will behave entirely the same for Django.

Comment: Thanks for response. I am not so affraid about django installation but more about application server/database server/security configuration.

Comment: Well, not meaning to be disrespectful - but you're basically asking how to be a system administrator. That's a very broad question, and there's a lot of self-help out there...or perhaps you know someone who can show you the ropes.